# ruby on rails rake db:migrate aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new on ruby on rails, I try to look for the answer to this type of problem. i have been looking for a long time and i haven't been able to find a solution.
I am working on windows vista home, ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.0.2.
I have try different ways to solve the problem and it seems that I do not understand what the output is telling me:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/database
c:/Users/me/desktop/family_N/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Users/me/desktop/family_N/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Thank you for your fast reply.
I install devise and try rake db:create, and i got the same output.
Forgive my ignorance but, this is what I am looking at
     db/migrate: 201405282050240_devise_create_user.rb.
     db/schema.rb: ActiveRecord::schema.define(version: 20140617211300) do |t| ...
do this dates have to match?

Answer (score 3):

Did you create your database? From the error posted, it would appear that you had not yet done so.

`rake db:create`

You do need to create the DB before you can migrate data to it.

Answer (score 0):

try `bundle exec rake db:create`